# Does GitHub support custom themes?

Tags: github

At https://github.com/settings/appearance, one can now choose between three themes: *Default light*, *Default dark* and *Dark dimmed*. Is it possible to fork those themes and modify them to personal taste, like it is possible with the Atom editor, or are the themes restricted to those three?

Comment: Please show what you tried as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén: There is nothing to try. There are only 3 options to choose from.